# You don't have permission to access / on this server. (AWS EC2 Ubuntu Laravel Project)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-4

I have an EC2 Ubuntu instance running on AWS that I have my site on.  Previously, I was able to get my site up and running (everything was working fine with url.com, www.url.com, or http://url.com.  Now none of these are working).

Now I get the message:

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.url.com Port 80

The only thing that changed was that I updated my laravel project (the framework for the site) from 4.0 to 4.1.

I'm at a loss as to why this changed.  Any ideas?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: This should not be necessary but *nix servers can go crazy for permissions. Make your web-server user the owner of the whole laravel folder. And give write permission for app/storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate application's directory to apache's user

```
chgrp -R www-data /var/www/laravel
```

Make storage folder writable so that laravel can write logs, cache & compiled views to it.

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/app/storage
```

After you have done this, everything should be back online.

Comment: You are amazing sir.  A gold star for you!